# An electrodinamic identity: starting point

Tags: electromagnetism, operators, maxwell-equations, calculus

With this request, I would like to ask you kindly how you can prove this identity. I thank you for those who can help me.

\begin{equation}
\overline{\nabla} \times (\overline{\nabla} \times \overline{E})=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\overline{\nabla} \times \overline{B})\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maxwell's version of Faraday's law of induction is
$$
\nabla\times {\bf E}= -\frac{\partial {\bf B}}{\partial t}.
$$
Now apply $\nabla\times$ to both sides.  Note that
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial t}(\nabla\times {\bf X})= \nabla\times\left( \frac{\partial {\bf X}}{\partial t}\right).
$$

Comment: I premise that my policy that I adopt in all sites including TeX.SE always and however positively rate the effort of a user. I think I have understood how to get there. But why is your second identity true?

Comment: For the same reason that $\partial^2/\partial x\partial y=\partial^2/\partial y\partial x$. It doesn’t matter in which order you take partial derivatives.

Comment: You can develop both sides and you'll see that the only thing that will change is the order of partial derivatives. For example, according to the second equation you have, for the $x$ axis: $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\dfrac{\partial X_z}{\partial y}-\dfrac{\partial X_y}{\partial z}\right)=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}(\dfrac{\partial X_z}{\partial t})-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}(\dfrac{\partial X_y}{\partial t})$

Which is true because of the Schwarz theorem  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives

Comment: @G.Smith I vote positively for the comment and an your answer.

Comment: @Syrocco See, please, the previous comment.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have forgot this.